# Why is there no "external" access modifier?

Tags: c#

Maybe I'm missing something but shouldn't C# have an external access modifier for methods? Ie an modifier that make an method public but only for other classes, ie the the method cannot be called by the class itself?

Wouldn't that be useful for things like public methods that do locking to ensure that the lock isn't reentred from within the class?

Comment: There is an `extern` keyword, but its not used for what you describe. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59b22c5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: This is only useful to programmers with multiple personality disorder. If you want methods un-accessible by a class, put them in a different class. By design, a oop class should have access and control over the methods and data contained within the class.

Answer (score 8):

There's no need for it. Access control is used to restrict access to members from *untrusted* client code.

Remember that in OOP, a class represents an autonomous, self-contained unit of code and is implicitly assumed to be self-consistent.

If you can't trust the code in your own class not to cause reentrancy then what can you trust? It's impractical to guard against every possible eventuality with language features; sometimes it's just up to you as a developer to make sure your own code works :)

Answer (score 5):

Interface methods with explicit implementation are probably the closest thing to what you want.  Of course, a class could still call them on itself if it casts `this` to the interface type.

Comment: Actually, I think the other answers are better.  I was going to go on a rant about how you ought not need this behavior, but the lure of coming up with a clever solution was too great.

Comment: [Progress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692.aspx) and the [IProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298.aspx) interface is a really good example of a good use of this. `IProgress<T>.Report` is a private member, so anyone creating a `Progress<T>` class does not see the `Report()` method, but all consumers who take in the `IProgress<T>` interface can call the `Report()` method to call back.

Answer (score 3):

I think it wouldn't be useful. There is no paradigm that defines any need for it.

In your example: even if there is the `external` keyword how do you ensure that the lock cannot be re-entered externally without releasing it?

There are contracts between classes, and the class is always in a contract with itself. I think no keyword can help to avoid such programming mistakes. In this particular example, the class should implement the locking properly depending on its level of usage.

Comment: I dunno, I think syntax that clarifies intent of code and ensures certain behavior is generally a good thing, that's why we have things like the readonly keyword. There's no reason why a class couldn't have a "contract" with itself

Answer (score 0):

this is my pen on Typescript.

Maybe this can be useful for anybody to describe the problem wich can be solved by external access modifier

[codepen](https://codepen.io/dmitry-chervakov/pen/ExaNRGW)

```
class ExternalUser {

  private static _time: number = 0;
  position: {x: number, y: number} = {x: 0, y: 0};

  constructor () {
    setInterval(this.bind(this.tick), 100);
  }

  external static set time(val: number) {
    ExternalUser._time = val;
  }

  static get time(): number {
    return ExternalUser._time;
  }

  private tick() {
    let someRandomThing = Math.random() > 0.95;
    if (someRandomThing) {
      ExternalUser.time += 100;// throws error, because set time is external
    }
    this.position={x: 10 * ExternalUser.time, y: ExternalUser.time * 10};
  }
}
```